# How to put TypeScript tsconfig in another location

Tags: typescript, tsconfig

I am trying to create a repo that houses our company's common linting rules in our locally hosted github instance.  This way we all have a common set of rules we can share easily. There are also configs for our typescript definitions, and PrettierJs rules.

The file structure looks like:

```
/lint-common
  /config
    .eslintrc.js
    .pretterrc
    tsconfig.json
  package.json
```

When installed in another project it looks like this:

```
/node_modules
  /lint-common
    /config
      .eslintrc.js
      .pretterrc
      tsconfig.json
    package.json 
package.json <-- Consuming package for the project that lint-common has been installed into
```

From my consuming project that has `lint-common` installed, I have scripts in the package.json that looks like this:

```
"scripts": {
  "lint": "eslint -c /node_modules/lint-common/config/.eslintrc.js --ext .js src",
  "pretty": "prettier --write --config /node_modules/lint-common/config/.prettierrc src/**/*.js"
}
```

This works fine so far.  But when I try to do this for `TypeScript`, it behaves quite differently.  Where `lint` and `pretty` process from the `src` directory I specify, the tsconfig insists on processing files from its own location.

For TypeScript, I tried to add a script like this:

```
"tsc": "tsc --p ../../config/tsconfig.json",
```

The `--p` is the `--project` option - which allows me to stipulate where the tsconfig file is.  Inside the tsconfig I have:

```
"include": ["src/**/*]
```

However, I only get the following error:

```
No inputs were found in config file ...
```

I can fix this by changing it to:

```
"include": ["../../../src/**/*]
```

The `include` option inside the tsconfig is searching for the files relative to the location of the tsconfig - not from where I am running the `npm` command from.

Is there a way I can get around this?  I have tried using the `rootDir` option, but that doesn't seem to have any effect.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Is there a way I can get around this?

The documentation doesn't mention a way, and AFAIK, there isn't.

I think a workable solution would be to include an npm [post-install] script which creates a `tsconfig.json` file, at the top level of a new project, which utilizes the [`extends`](https://www.typescriptlang.org/tsconfig#extends) property to reference the config nested within `node_modules`.

Comment: Thanks jsejcksn.  That ended up working just fine. :)